# Spring boot 2X not able to connect mongoDb - MongoDbFactory has deprecated

Tags: spring, mongodb, spring-boot, spring-boot-maven-plugin

I am using spring boot 2.6.6

```
<parent>
        <groupId>org.springframework.boot</groupId>
        <artifactId>spring-boot-starter-parent</artifactId>
        <version>2.6.6</version>
        <relativePath />
        <!-- lookup parent from repository -->
    </parent>
```

MongoDb -

```
<!-- https://mvnrepository.com/artifact/org.mongodb/mongo-java-driver -->
        <dependency>
            <groupId>org.mongodb</groupId>
            <artifactId>mongo-java-driver</artifactId>
        <version>3.12.10</version>
```

Code -

```
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Bean;
import org.springframework.context.annotation.Configuration;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.MongoTemplate;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultDbRefResolver;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.DefaultMongoTypeMapper;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.convert.MappingMongoConverter;
import org.springframework.data.mongodb.core.mapping.MongoMappingContext;

@Configuration
public class MongoDBConfiguration {

    
@Bean
public MongoTemplate mongoTemplate(MongoDbFactory mongoDbFactory, MongoMappingContext context) {                
        MappingMongoConverter converter = new MappingMongoConverter(new DefaultDbRefResolver(mongoDbFactory), context);
        converter.setTypeMapper(new DefaultMongoTypeMapper(null));
        MongoTemplate mongoTemplate = new MongoTemplate(mongoDbFactory, converter);

        return mongoTemplate;

    }
    
}
```

Application Properties -

spring.data.mongodb.uri=mongodb://mypath

Error -

```
The injection point has the following annotations:
    - @org.springframework.beans.factory.annotation.Autowired(required=true)

Action:

Consider defining a bean of type 'org.springframework.data.mongodb.MongoDbFactory' in your configuration.
```

**Looks like - MongoDbFactory methods has deprecated. May I know how I can connect to it ?**

Answer (score 2):

I have used this to solve the problem -

```
@Bean
    public MongoDatabaseFactory mongoDatabaseFactory(){
        logger.info("configuring mongo db template !!!");
        return new SimpleMongoClientDatabaseFactory(dataSourceMongoDBURL);
    }
```